# raspberry pi for web programming/development

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm into web development and my machine (AMD Phenom II, 8G RAM) is running Ubuntu 13.04. I love my current setup but I kinda miss some of Windows software like MSOffice or Adobe suites, and running on Virtualbox doesn't feel as snappy for me.... So I'm thinking of buying a new cheap machine where I would install Linux and do my development work there and have my current machine run Windows.

I just found this thing called Raspberry pi which is really cheap and requires 12v only (I think) which makes it good for downloading stuff overnight. So, does it make sense to buy Raspberry pi, make it my primary dev machine, Windows being the secondary (for Adobe and browser testing of course)?

Basically, I want to know if Raspberry pi meets the following requirements:

- It should run ArchLinux
- Sublime Text 3
- python
- ruby
- nginx
- nodejs
- Deluge or Transmission
- (well, maybe just those, no need for videos and music players)

Comment: There isn't a `Sublime Text 3` for ARM yet.  Otherwise, I think you are covered with a PI.  Though they are fairly slow, so your development may be hindered slightly.  But if it's headless, it's much better.

Comment: Alternative options for you: 1) Dual Boot 2) Run Windows and run virtualbox headless for web devel (requires some setup, but not too hard) 3) Use WAMP (lamp on windows) or use Python to make a simple (or complex) web server in Windows.  If you go the Pi route, do not run xserver and just use it as a headless box - since you're already complaining about 'snappiness'.

Comment: The raspi runs off 5V - I use a phone charger on mine, though at one point, I just powered it off a desktop's USB ports

Comment: I've tried developing something on Raspi, it was so slow you had to wait half a second after pressing PageUp. Why not just dual boot Ubuntu and Windows on your current machine?

Comment: Install Virtualbox on your machine and boot Windows inside it. Buy a Raspberry anyway. They are fun.

Comment: @Squeezy I would definitely buy as Raspberry, I really think they are cool.

Answer (score 1):

Not gonna lie. The RPi is not a speed demon. You can run all those on there (except Sublime perhaps), but you'll probably want to do your development on the Windows machine, using a DVCS to push your code the the RPi.

Answer (score 1):

Rasberri Pi is something like the "stone soup" of computers.  After you add a disk, a display, and an operating system license (for your other machine) you have the price of a real computer.  Of course, if you already had these things lying around, you might have a lot of fun putting it together.